# How do we configure DataSource in Liberty Server for native connection

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I'm getting following exception while unwrapping native connection from `WSJDbConnection` connection object:

```
Exception data: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Below steps I have tried to solve

1. added additional parameter `enableConnectionCasting` to get native connection.
2. ```
   DataSource ds = InitialContext.lookup("jdbc/oracleDb");
   OracleConnection con= (OracleConnection) ds.getConnection();
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes in the server.xml

1) Datasource definition which points to common library

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/test">
     <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
         <properties.oracle
             URL=""
             password=""
             user=""
         />
 </dataSource>
```

2) library definition

```
<library id="OracleLib">
     <fileset dir="resources/oracle" includes="*.jar"/>
 </library>
```

3) Add the classloader to application configuration, which points to the same library as used by the Datasource and make sure that ojdbc*.jar is not included in the application

```
 <webApplication id="OracleWrapper" location="OracleWrapper.war"  name="OracleWrapper">
     <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleLib">
     </classloader>
 </webApplication>
```